# Liferay Portlet Issue

Tags: liferay

Im new with liferay have a problem with portlet deployment using the plugins sdk,

Platform:
liferay-portal-tomcat-5.5-5.1.2,
liferay-plugins-sdk-5.2.2,
windows vista.

Problem:
I have successfully created a sample portlet with ant and deployed it into the hot-deploy folder. It is automatically picked up by the server but the console messages say that the portlet has been copied successfully and never registers it.. and i cant find it in the add application drop-down menu.. pls your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anything important changed in these versions, but you say you're using Liferay 5.1.2 with the plugin environment 5.2.2 - try with matching versions - at least on the second digit.

also, make sure that all required files are available - among them are WEB-INF/web.xml, WEB-INF/portlet.xml.

Create a new sample portlet with "create.bat" in the plugin SDK's portlet folder and deploy this - it should succeed. Then make sure that all config files from the new one are present in your current one.

How did you create your current portlet? What did you do/change?